# How to execute cgi script from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I need to give user a button on the webpage in order to download a file. User will enter the filename in text box on the page and once the button is clicked, the user should get the file. But, when I am running the below code, the file is not being downloaded. Please suggest. 
Javascript code that should execute CGI code.

javascript code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT Language="Javascript">

function go_to() {
    document.location = "/opt/IBM/netcool/gui/omnibus_webgui/etc/cgi-bin/download_csv.cgi";
}

</SCRIPT>
<a href='webtop/cgi-bin/download_csv.cgi'>Link text</a>
<IMG SRC="BLAH" onClick="go_to()">
</BODY>
```

cgi code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI 'header';
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $files_location = "/home/netcool";

my $filename = 'Maintenance_File.csv';

if (!$filename) {
  die "You must specify a file to download";
  exit;
}

print header(
  -type => 'text/csv',
  -content_disposition => "attachment;filename=$filename",
);

my $fileloc = "$files_location/$filename";
open my $fh, '<', $fileloc or Error('open', 'file', $!);
print while <$fh>;
close $fh or Error ('close', 'file' );

sub Error {
  die "@_";
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? ("it is not able to download the file" is not an adequate description of the problem.)

Comment: Try to change `document.location =` to `document.location.href =`

Comment: I can't help noticing that the js code shown sets `document.location` to what looks like the filesystem path of the CGI script. OP probably needs to set up a web server of some sort, enable CGI execution for that server, and then set `document.location` (or `...href`) to the URL corresponding to the CGI script, so that it will be executed instead of just sending back the CGI source code.

Comment: @DaveSherohman :  I am not sure about the code as I am new  to javascript. Basically,the requirement is to download a file,once user clicks on Download button.Now If i need to execute cgi script,once user clicks on Download button then How can I do that ?? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need Javascript here. Create an HTML form with the required input fields and an action which points to the CGI program.

Comment: @SaurabhJain: You seem to be missing some fundamental knowledge of how web programming works. I wonder if it would be useful to spend a few hours working through this tutorial - http://ovid-cgi-course.perl-begin.org/cgi-course/.